# Auto Calculate with already given value

Tags: javascript

I want to get fee value with already calculated value without using `onblur` function.

HTML and JS Snippet:

```js
var initialcost = document.getElementById("initialcost");
var Tfee = initialcost - (initialcost * 5)/100;
document.getElementById("fee").value = +Tfee;
```

```html
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="1000" id="initialcost">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"  id="fee">
```

After autocalculating read-only value from `id="initialcost"` display the value in `id="fee"`

After trying this I get no result
Kindly help

Comment: When stuck, try always to i.e: `console.log(initialcost)` or use breakpoints in your development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to calculate things using the element, not its value.

Replace

```
var initialcost = document.getElementById("initialcost");
```

with

```
var initialcost = parseFloat(document.getElementById("initialcost").value);
```

Example with automatic recalculation to boot:

```js
var initialCostElement = document.getElementById("initialcost");
function compute() {
  var initialcost = parseFloat(initialCostElement.value);
  var Tfee = initialcost - (initialcost * 5)/100;
  document.getElementById("fee").value = +Tfee;
}

initialCostElement.addEventListener("input", compute, false);
compute();
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1000" id="initialcost">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"  id="fee">
```

Comment: @Dominic It does certainly work. I added a runnable snippet too.

Answer (score 0):

first of all,
you are using the html element itself instead of its value in your calculation.

use:

```
 var initialcost = document.getElementById("initialcost").value;
```

Moreover, I would replace the "var" type with contest in both variables since this are constants with non-changing values. The var is a more "old-fashioned" approach since "let" and "const" are newer additions to the js syntax,
Good luck!